# Preventing pushes from a branch to a specific remote

Tags: git

I would like to maintain two forks of a project: one for internal use at the company and another one for opensource. I'd like to have all deploy-specific elements in the source tree (like the deployment recipe and the database configuration and a version-specific bootstrap file and so on).

The way I envisioned it was that i'd have two branches, for example `master` and `internal`. In that case one thing I'd like to prevent is pushing the `internal` branch to Github since that would contain sensitive information. I'd then cherry-pick changes from the `internal` branch into master.

So how do I configure remotes that a branch is pushed to it's default remote? I have to setup that branch to track another remote than Github?

Or is there a better workflow to developing two forks in lockstep for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once someone has cloned your repo, he (or she of course) has full access to all branches stored in the repo. **You cannot prevent him (or her of course) from pushing the complete repo to somewhere** or even make the sources public on the internet.

If you want to keep secret things secret, set up **two repos**, one for `master` and one for `internal` and then `cherry-pick` the needed commits from `internal` to `master` like you intended to do.

To achieve this, add the `internal` repo as remote to the `master` repo. While being on `master` do

```
git remote add internal /path/to/internal
```

When you want to take commits from `internal` to `master`, simply [`fetch`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-fetch.html) the latest revisions of `internal` into `master`

```
git fetch internal
```

then check the commits to be taken and [`cherry-pick`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html) them using

```
git cherry-pick <SHA1>
```